# Why the program didn't execute some sentences in this C programming or unix programming(execvp() System calls)?

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec, wait

I have the following program, when I run the program, I feel really confused that why my program didn't excute

```
   int num=i;
       printf("it is No.%d !",num);
       printf("hello , I will excute execvp!");
```

My program basically create 6 child processes to excute executionbode() function, and then use execvp to overload original program. However, everytime when I run the program, the string "hello, I will execute execvp" never shows up! Also I think those three sentences above also didn't execute in the running program? can someone tell me why? Here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "makeargv.h"
#include "redirection.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>



int executionnode(int i);

int main(){
pid_t childpid;
     int i;
     int row=6;
     for(i=0;i<row;i++)
     {   childpid=fork();
         if(childpid==0)
            continue;
         else if (childpid>0)
            executionnode(i);

         else {
           perror("something wrong");
            exit(1);
          }
      }


}


int executionnode(int i){
   sleep(i);
   printf("hello, I am process:%ld\n",(long)getpid());
   wait(NULL);
   char *execArgs[] = { "echo", "Hello, World!", NULL };
   int num=i;
   printf("it is No.%d !",num);
   printf("hello , I will excute execvp!");
   execvp("echo", execArgs);

}
```

Can someone tell me why? and how to fix it? I feel it is really strange? Is it because of execvp() functions? I just began to learn operating system,so I am really confused about it! Thank you for helping me!

Comment: 1) use the debugger 2) Read the man-page of `wait`

Comment: Here's a hint: who are the child processes waiting for and why? Answering that question will go a long way to solving your problem. Also, it's more precise to say that `execvp` overwrites the *current* process image.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is the result of the combination of 2 different things:

**1** -  As *tonysdg* mentioned in the comment, execvp overwites the current process image, and to quote [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and
>   stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program
>   loaded.

(*`execvp()` is a front-end for `execve()`*)

and

**2** - The stdout is a buffered stream, which means that the actual printing takes place when a newline character is found or the buffer is flushed.

(see more on this at *Rudd Zwolinski's* answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716621/4711309) )

---

So, now, let's see how these things interact and produce your issue:
Just before you call `execvp()` your output buffer already contains the contents of the 2 previous *printf's*, however since there is no newline character, nothing is printed on the screen.

Then, `execvp()` is executed and overwrites everything on your current process, which of course means that the contents of your 'previous' output buffer are lost.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) you can find many ways to address this issue and, just for completeness, I suggest you add `\n` to the final `printf`:

```
...
printf("hello , I will excute execvp!\n");
...
```

and then you're good to go:

```
$ ./soc
hello, I am process:4701
hello, I am process:4702
hello, I am process:4703
hello, I am process:4704
hello, I am process:4705
hello, I am process:4706
it is No.5 !hello , I will excute execvp!
Hello, World!
it is No.4 !hello , I will excute execvp!
Hello, World!
it is No.3 !hello , I will excute execvp!
Hello, World!
it is No.2 !hello , I will excute execvp!
Hello, World!
it is No.1 !hello , I will excute execvp!
Hello, World!
it is No.0 !hello , I will excute execvp!
Hello, World!
```